# Use bash variable to access command arguments?

Tags: bash, variables

Say for instance I have 
`x=1` and I want to access the first arg, i.e., `$1`. How can I do so using x? I've tried

```
$($x)
$( {$x} )
```

but to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like you want an [indirect expansion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41292/67817)

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction! Glad to know theres a term for it :)